Ansible command fails to execute on managed_node
I just started learning Linux and Ansible and I'm having an issue running the command:
ansible all -m user -a 'name=test2 state=present'

I have two machines. One is controller_node and the other is managed_node. On managed_node I have created user automation and added it to the wheel group (sudoers: Using Rocky Linux) but whenever I try to run the above command from the controller_node I get the following error:

